# Why I can not login to magento 2 backend using google chrome

Tags: magento, magento2

I am using magento community edition 2. I am not able to login to back end of magento. I know this problem can be because of chrome not accepting cookies. In previous versions(Magento 1.9.1,1.9.0, & so on) I normally go to `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php` file and comment the below lines to fix the above mentioned chrome browser issue,

```
$this->getCookie()->getDomain(), 
$this->getCookie()->isSecure(), 
$this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
```

But Magento 2 Folder structure is different.
How do I fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another browser to set the cookie time and HTTPS settings to its correct values. You should now be able to use Chrome again.